# Doesn't get() break the idea behind std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

Example code:

```
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<int> intPtr{new int(3)};

  int* myPtr = intPtr.get();

  *myPtr = 4;

  std::cout<<"New result for intPtr: "<< *intPtr.get()<<std::endl;

}
```

Doesn't this defeat the whole purpose behind `std::unique_ptr` ? Why is this allowed?

Edit: I thought the whole purpose behind std::unique_ptr was to have sole ownership of an object. But this example, the object can be modified through another pointer. Doesn't this defeat std::unique_ptr's purpose?

Comment: To interface with C APIs..?

Comment: Because `int* myPtr = intPtr.operator->();` would be harder to read? `unique_ptr` has no choice but to expose the raw pointer in some way - otherwise, how would you access anything pointed to?

Comment: `unique_ptr` doesn't exist to prevent aliasing. It exists to allow one (and only one) "owner" of object lifetime. `myPtr` doesn't "own" the lifetime of the `int`.

Comment: If I invite you to have a lunch in my home, you modify the content on my house, without being owner ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While [Smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) manage the lifetime of an object being pointed to, it is often still useful to have access to the underlying raw pointer.

In fact if we read Herb Sutter's [GotW #91 Solution: Smart Pointer Parameters](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/) he recommends passing parameters by pointer or reference when the function is agnostic to the lifetime of the parameter, he says:

> Pass by * or & to accept a widget independently of how the caller is
>   managing its lifetime. Most of the time, we don’t want to commit to a
>   lifetime policy in the parameter type, such as requiring the object be
>   held by a specific smart pointer, because this is usually needlessly
>   restrictive.

and we should pass by [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) when the function is a *sink*:

> Passing a unique_ptr by value is only possible by moving the object
>   and its unique ownership from the caller to the callee. Any function
>   like (c) takes ownership of the object away from the caller, and
>   either destroys it or moves it onward to somewhere else.

and finally pass a `unique_ptr` by reference when we can potentially modify it to refer to a different object:

> This should only be used to accept an in/out unique_ptr, when the
>   function is supposed to actually accept an existing unique_ptr and
>   potentially modify it to refer to a different object. It is a bad way
>   to just accept a widget, because it is restricted to a particular
>   lifetime strategy in the caller.

Of course, we are required to get the underlying pointer if we have to interface with C libraries that take pointers.

In your specific example:

```
int* myPtr = intPtr.get();
```

There is no transfer of ownership to another smart pointer so there are no problems as long as you don't attempt to `delete` the pointer via `myPtr`. You can transfer ownership to another `unique_ptr` by moving it:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> intPtr2( std::move( intPtr ) ) ;
```

Answer (score 9):

The example you have shown does not defeat the purpose of `std::unique_ptr`, which is to **maintain ownership of memory allocation and deallocation**.  The line `std::unique_ptr<int> intPtr{new int(3)}` allocates a new `int` and takes ownership of it.

The line `*myPtr = 4` does not change that ownership, it is merely **assigning a value to the content of the `int`**, via a pointer retrieved by `std::unique_ptr::get()`.  The `std::unique_ptr` still owns the allocated memory for the `int`.

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't defeat the purpose of `unique_ptr` at all. The type of smart pointer determines the ownership semantics, but there may be a case where you need to use the underlying object. For example you have an object owned by a `unique_ptr` but need to call a method that expect the object by reference. You can then dereference the `.get()` pointer to get the reference object to pass to the method.

What you *shouldn't* do is store the obtained pointer in a way that acquires ownership. This is one of the cases where the language gives you tools to work properly and if you take the raw pointer and store a second ownership to it then that's a problem with the use of the tool.

Comment: The given example isn't a great one, since you should just do [`*ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*) for that case.

Answer (score 3):

Get just allows you to obtain the raw pointer. Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to use a pointer-based API when you have a `unique_ptr`, as the only alternative is `release`, which would make the unique pointer useless. So you get `get`, which allows using pointer-based APIs without forcing everyone to use an `unique_ptr`. Without `get`, you could only call -> and * on the pointer, but if you have a primitive type, that would kind of defeat of having an `unique_ptr` in the first place.